# Sum value from data attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Supposing I have this:

```
<div>
    <p id="bilingual_rate" data-item-rate="50">50 $</p>
    <p id="domain_rate" data-item-rate="50">50 $</p>
    <p id="hosting_rate" data-item-rate="250">250 $</p>
    <p id="ssl_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="gmaps_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="admin_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="ga_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="catalogue_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="online-store_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="blog_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="gallery_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="contact-form_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="newsletter_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
</div>
```

How can I loop into this HTML to sum the value of the `data-item-rate` ?

This is what I tried:

```js
function updateTotal() {

  var total = 0;
  $('p[data-item-rate]').each(function() {
    total += $(this).data('item-rate');
  });

  alert(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="bilingual_rate" data-item-rate="50">50 $</p>
  <p id="domain_rate" data-item-rate="50">50 $</p>
  <p id="hosting_rate" data-item-rate="250">250 $</p>
  <p id="ssl_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="gmaps_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="admin_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="ga_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="catalogue_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="online-store_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="blog_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="gallery_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="contact-form_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
  <p id="newsletter_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Code looks like it should run fine. What problem are you having? How do you call your function? Are you getting errors?

Comment: jQuery `data()` returns a string. That way you would be concatenating strings instead of adding integers. Change it to `total += ($(this).data('item-rate')-0)`. The `-0` converts each string to an integer value.

Comment: @cars10m not necessary here; works fine as-is

Comment: @cars10m `data()` will return a `number`, if the data can be coerced.  It is not guarenteed to always return a string.  https://jsfiddle.net/7oq2nh58/

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS one-liner using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (which is designed for exactly this kind of job):

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('[data-item-rate]')].reduce((a, v)=>a+Number(v.dataset.itemRate),0));

// if you insist on involving jQuery:
console.log([...$('[data-item-rate]')].reduce((a, v)=>a+Number(v.dataset.itemRate),0));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p id="bilingual_rate" data-item-rate="50">50 $</p>
    <p id="domain_rate" data-item-rate="50">50 $</p>
    <p id="hosting_rate" data-item-rate="250">250 $</p>
    <p id="ssl_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="gmaps_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="admin_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="ga_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="catalogue_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="online-store_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="blog_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="gallery_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="contact-form_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
    <p id="newsletter_rate" data-item-rate=""></p>
</div>
```

From the mdn documentation for `reduce`:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

The reducer function is this part:

```
(a, v)=>a+Number(v.dataset.itemRate
```

It uses ES6 arrow notation. In ES5 Javascript the following would be exactly the same, just less concise:

```
function (a, v) { return a+Number(v.dataset.itemRate) }
```

Comment: How does a translation resolve whatever problem is occurring?

Comment: OP's question: *How can I loop into this HTML to sum the value of the data-item-rate ?* Answers are not required to work with whatever OP has so far.

Comment: Yes, but a direction was provided that should be respected unless there's reason not to.

Comment: There actually is reason: jQuery is no longer necessary in 2019. For 99.99% of cases.

Comment: For all you know there's 3MB of jQuery on the site already and it harms nothing to use it here, for readability and quick development. I've been writing JavaScript and jQuery for a decade, and your one-liner is not an easy read.

Comment: The other reason is that this is a parade case for `Array.prototype.reduce`. And how do you even know the site has *3 MB of jQuery code* -  sites likes that are destined to die. Nobody refactors that amount of code to vanilla JS - which is why sites like these will be completely re-written from scratch at some point.

Comment: I *highly* doubt that a user that can't get a simple loop fixed is going to understand how `$('[data-item-rate]')].reduce((a, v)=>a+Number(v.dataset.itemRate),0)` works without an explanation

Comment: @j08691 You have a point there. Feel free to add what you consider necessary to my answer. I added a link to mdn and a short excerpt and which part of the solution I provided that applies to.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you haven't called the function.

```
updateTotal();
```

It works fine. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tnx7dqL9/)

Answer (score 0):

call each on class ,  add a class to p element .

```
function updateTotal() {

 var total = 0;
 $('.rate').each(function() {
 total += $(this).data('item-rate');
 });
```

}